# Similar Objective-C KVO in c++

Tags: c++, objective-c, function-pointers, key-value-observing

I have this architetture:

I have a thread that continuously monitors the status of a shared variable.
I would like to develop a system similar to Objective-C `KVO` in c++ . In practice, I would like to notify to a thread02 the state change of a variable.

What do you call this kind of pattern?

What is the best way and easiest way to accomplish this?

I thought I can have a method of thread01 addObserver where you pass a function pointer, but I would like to be the thread02 executing the code of this function (when he'll be ready)

Do you have suggestions?

Some examples?

Comment: Although you get a whole framework, you might want to take a look at Qt and it's signal/slot mechanism which provides observability even between threads.

Answer (score 3):

It's called the Observer pattern, and was originally described in the [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) book. Examples in C++ exist [e.g. at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328365/Understanding-and-Implementing-Observer-Pattern-in).

To solve your threading problems, the callback function you supply to the observed object should act as a signal, which should wake the other thread and tell it to start its work. You could use a [condition variable](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs140/cgi-bin/lecture.php?topic=locks) for this signal.